# Is it possible for the transfer function of an RLC system to have zeros other than at the origin?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I could not find a counterexample to the claim that the transfer function of an RLC system can only have zeros at the origin. Is this a true statement?

Comment: You mean an RLC series combination, an RLC parallel combination, or an arbitary network of resistors, inductors and capacitors?

Comment: This smells like homework. Think a little harder.

Comment: @ThePhoton an arbitrary network.

Comment: @MattYoung this is not homework - it's just an observation I had while looking at transfer functions of RLC networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2xlg4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One pole, one zero. Neither one is at the origin.

Or, even simpler, if you're willing to consider a transimpedance transfer function:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCkLLM.png)</sup>

The transimpedance (\$v_{out}/i_{in}\$) has just one zero, and it's not at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPoCW2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$H(j\omega_0) = 0 $$

$$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}} $$